# Multiple attachments with in contact form

Tags: php, attachment

How can i make a contact form with the possibility to sent multiple attachements? I want only one upload field.

Comment: You should have done a basic google search before asking this question here..

Answer (score 1):

Sample code to see that

[Code](http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/07/17/upload-multiple-files-at-once-with-php/)

http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/07/17/upload-multiple-files-at-once-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

The [uploadify jquery plugin](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/) can be used for this. see also: [contact form with file upload support](http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/contact-form-attachment.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the HTML5 multiple upload form. Here is an example `http://snipplr.com/view/47210/php-html5-multifile-upload/`. But just be careful when using it as not many browsers support HTML5 features.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of scripts available for Multiple file upload. You can select one according to your specific requirement. It will be better if you select one with a progress bar. When ever you do multiple file upload, it will take lot of time which will give a feeling on site broken. You could simpoly search the internet and get one.

http://ajaxian.com/archives/asynchronous-file-upload-with-ajax-progress-bar-in-php

http://www.ultramegatech.com/blog/2010/10/create-an-upload-progress-bar-with-php-and-jquery/